How to find 4-acceleration $A^i A_i = \dfrac{dU^i}{ds} \dfrac{dU_i}{ds}$ for $ds=\sqrt{dx^i dx_i}$ not $ds=cd\tau$?
In special relativiy, 4-velocity $U^i=\dfrac{dx^i}{ds}$ for $ds=\sqrt{dx^idx_i}$.
Therefore we have, $U^iU_i=\dfrac{dx^i}{ds}\dfrac{dx_i}{ds}=\dfrac{dx^idx_i}{ds^2}= \dfrac{dx^idx_i}{dx^idx_i}=1$.
So what would be the value for 4-acceleration i.e, $A^iA_i=\dfrac{dU^i}{ds} \dfrac{dU_i}{ds}$ if we substitute $ds=\sqrt{dx^idx_i}$ instead of $ds=cd\tau$ ?
If we do by putting $ds=cd\tau$, it give the obvious result after second derivative of the 4-position vector , this much is clear but i am confused for the above approach.

This question is a duplicate of: Acceleration from General Relativity.

Note that you cannot use the same index for seperate inner products, that is why you should have had
$$
u^\mu u_\mu = \frac{\mathrm{d}x^\mu}{\mathrm{d}s}\frac{\mathrm{d}x_\mu}{\mathrm{d}s} = \frac{\mathrm{d}x^\mu\mathrm{d}x_\mu}{\mathrm{d}x^\nu\mathrm{d}x_\nu} = 1
$$
instead, or even
$$
u^\mu u_\mu = \frac{\mathrm{d}x^\mu}{\mathrm{d}s}\frac{\mathrm{d}x_\mu}{\mathrm{d}s} = \frac{\mathrm{d}s^2}{\mathrm{d}s^2} = 1
$$
in a more natural style, although it does not make any trouble in the present case. As for the 4-acceleration, this substitution is actually equivalent to a (kind of useless) change of variable, that brings you nowhere. Indeed, one has :
$$
a^\mu a_\mu 
   = \frac{\mathrm{d}u^\mu}{\mathrm{d}s}\frac{\mathrm{d}u_\mu}{\mathrm{d}s} 
   = \frac{\mathrm{d}u^\mu}{\sqrt{\mathrm{d}x^\rho\mathrm{d}x_\rho}} \frac{\mathrm{d}u_\mu}{\sqrt{\mathrm{d}x^\sigma\mathrm{d}x_\sigma}}
   = \frac{\mathrm{d}u^\mu}{\mathrm{d}x^\nu}\frac{\mathrm{d}u_\mu}{\mathrm{d}x_\nu},
$$
which cannot be simplified further.
